# count rows from a single table based on multiple conditions using SQL

Tags: sql, select, null, where-clause

I am trying to achieve what appears to be simple but I cannot figure it out. I have a table, test_score..

```
----------------------
ID   | Date | Score
---------------------
345 | dt1  | 80
346 | dt1  | NULL
347 | dt1  | NULL
345 | dt1  | NULL
348 | dt2  | 75
```

The table can have multiple entries with the ID_Date pair.. for eg., for ID 345 and dt1, there are two entries, one with a score and another NULL value. I want to fetch those rows that have NULL values ONLY.

In this example, return rows with IDs, 346 and 347.. It MUST be an ID_Date pair and both of these are NON-NULL values

My attempts so far:
Select rows for which score is NULL, ID and date is not null INTERSECT select rows for which score is NOT NULL and ID and Date are NOT NULL.
This gives me a count of rows, where these id_date pairs exist in BOTH score_is_null and score_is_not_null conditions.. I subtract this from the total rows where score is NULL.. but my results are incorrect.

Second approach.

```
SELECT id || date AS temp, count(*)
FROM test_score
WHERE score IS NULL AND id IS NOT NULL AND date IS NOT NULL
AND pairs NOT IN 
(SELECT id || date AS temp
FROM test_Score 
WHERE score IS NOT NULL AND id IS NOT NULL AND date IS NOT NULL)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the pairs, then use aggregation:

```
select id, date
from test_score
group by id, date
having max(score) is null;
```

If for some reason you actually want the original rows, use `not exists`:

```
select ts.*
from test_score ts
where not exists (select 1
                  from test_score ts2
                  where ts2.id = ts.id and ts2.date = ts.date and ts2.score is not null
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(id, date, score)`.

Comment: I think this is similar to the query I posted.. I tried it but it takes over 20 min and I do not yet get a result.. I have over 700K rows. : ( The whole idea is ID and Date as a pair must be unique since there are multiple records with the same combination.. that is why I tried to concatenate them.. I only want the count of those ID and Date pairs that have only null values for score..

Comment: @DolphinB . . . I don't really see the similarity.  But try with the specified index (which I just added.

Comment: How long should this query approximately take? The data is downloaded to my computer, so it is just memory usage. It either did not complete or hung when I left it for over an hour..

Comment: With the specified index, the second query should be pretty fast.  Of course, the performance depends on your data, the computer you are running on, and lots of other things as well.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your query seems to address exactly what I want but I can never get it to finish running. I tried several times the past few hours... Out of curiosity, can I concat ids and date into a single identifier, create a column, then use this identifier directly instead of checking for each entry? I tried doing it (as shown in my code in the question) but I am not getting the right answer..

Answer (score 0):

One simple method would be:

```
Select ids, dt, score from (Select t.*, max(score) OVER (PARTITION BY ids, dt) mx from tab1 t)
where mx IS NULL
```

Then another method would be:

```
Select ids, dt, score from (Select t.*, count(ids) OVER (PARTITION BY ids, dt) mx from tab1 t)
where mx = 1 and score is NULL;
```

Comment: I want ID and Date as a pair (as a single identifier).. Can I use that in  PARTITION BY ?

Comment: Absolutely, Let me edit my answer and add the date in the partition by.

Comment: Thanks The AG. I tried this one and it works pretty fast and I got similar results with a messy complicated query I wrote earlier. I think there is something I am missing, because I do not get the expected results..